# Sizing a HorizontalPanel cell in GXT

Tags: gwt, gxt

Inside our (GXT)HorizontalPanel are two components.

I want to set the width for the first component to 100%. In GWT there is a method like HorizontalPanel#setCellWidth (see [Sizing a HorizontalPanel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666299/sizing-a-horizontalpanel-cell)). But in GXT there is not method like that.

We use GXT 2.3.1 and I DON'T want to use a GWT HorizontalPanel. It has to be a GXT HorizontalPanel (please don't ask why ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Here is some code that works for me.

```
public class HPanel extends HorizontalPanel {
    public HPanel(){
        Widget widget1 = new Widget();
        Widget widget2 = new Widget()

        TableData tableData = new TableData();
        tableData.setWidth("100%");
        setLayoutData(widget1, tableData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS style.

Java

```
widget.setStyleName("myStyle");
```

css:

```
.myStyle{
     width:100%;
}
```

Comment: First I had this idea, too. But it didn't worked for me. But I found a solution (see my answer).

Comment: have a look at [gxt-2.2.5-HorizontalPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/HorizontalPanel.html) Code snippet.